# Converting c++ to c# code for image color matching script

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, code-conversion

I'm trying to create a script to match the colours between two images using EmguCV.

I've managed to find code that does exactly what I want to, [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/178127/matching-colors-between-two-pictures-in-opencv/), however it's written in C++ which I'm not very familiar with.

I'm sure a lot of these things are basic C++ -> C# issues even if you're not familiar with EmguCV / OpenCV...

So far I'm stumped on the following (see code below).

1. 'mask(p)' - mask is of type Mat, and this produces an error in C#: 'a method name is expected'. I presume that the code is trying to index the mask but not sure how to do this. There are quite a few of these instances in the code.
2. 'chns[i]' - probably similar to the above, chns is again of type Mat, and this produces the error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Mat".
3. With 'mask(p)' above, and the other various instances, once the issue above is corrected I suspect that there will be another issue in comparing the Mat with an integer to iterate through - perhaps this is looking at the columns or the rows, I'm not sure. (I'm referring to, for example 'if (mask(p) > 0)' )
4. With 'CvInvoke.Split(src, chns)' creates an error 'Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Emgu.CV.Mat> to Emgu.CV.IOutputArray'. I assume I need to define chns and chns1 to an IOutputArray - although I'm not sure how to do this - declaring an IOutputArray using new OutputArray requires an IntPtr reference (possibly 'new Mat()'? and a parent - not quite sure what's required here. lease see below.

I've run the original C++ code through a C++ to C# converter to get rid of the obvious issues, and have made as many changes as I can to convert OpenCV calls to EmguCV, and I'm left with the below. Any help in deciphering the remaining parts would be most gratefully received.

Further assumptions that I've applied:

1. In referencing 'Mat' in the method names, I don't think C# requires you to specify the depth as you do in C++, so I've removed the  and  references, but instead updated the DepthTypes when the mats are declared, e.g. 'new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);' (in the case of double)
2. Updated variable types, e.g. 'uchar' -> 'byte'
3. Other conversions have been annoted, apart from obvious OpenCV -> EmguCV conversions that are clearly correct.

Code I've got to so far:

```
public static class EmguCVColourMatchingHelper
{

    // Compute histogram and CDF for an image with mask
    // C++: void do1ChnHist(const Mat_<uchar> &img, const Mat_<uchar> &mask, Mat_<double> &h, Mat_<double> &cdf)
    public static void do1ChnHist(Mat img, Mat mask, Mat h, Mat cdf)
    {
        // C++: for (size_t p = 0; p<img.total(); p++)
        for (var p = 0; p < (Int32)img.Total; p++)
        {
            if (mask(p) > 0)        // ERROR (Issue 1): 'Mat mask - Method name expected' - happens with all Mat types followed by ().
            {
                byte c = img(p);    // ERROR (Issue 1)
                h(c) += 1.0;        // ERROR (Issue 1)
            }
        }

        CvInvoke.Normalize(h, h, 1, 0, NormType.MinMax);

        cdf(0) = h(0);                      // ERROR (Issue 1)
        for (int j = 1; j < 256; j++)
        {
            cdf(j) = cdf(j - 1) + h(j);     // ERROR (Issue 1)
        }

        CvInvoke.Normalize(cdf, cdf, 1, 0, NormType.MinMax);
    }

    public static void histMatchRGB(Mat src, Mat src_mask, Mat dst, Mat dst_mask)
    {
        double histmatch_epsilon = 0.000001;

        // C++: vector<Mat_<uchar>> chns, chns1;
        //  List<Mat> chns = new List<Mat>(); - this is the main way to convert vector<Mat> chns, chns1 - however itn's not compatible with CvInvoke.Split below
        //  I think I need to declare an IOutputArray below, but not exactly sure how to do this.
        IOutputArray chns = new OutputArray(new Mat(), something??);    // Issue 4.

        CvInvoke.Split(src, chns);
        CvInvoke.Split(dst, chns1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            // C++: Mat_<double> src_hist = Mat_<double>::zeros(1, 256); etc...
            //     NOTE: here I've assumed 1 channel (last '1' reference in new statements below), as I think we're iterating through RGB
            Mat src_hist = new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);
            Mat dst_hist = new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);
            Mat src_cdf = new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);
            Mat dst_cdf = new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);

            do1ChnHist(chns[i], src_mask, src_hist, src_cdf);   // ERROR (Issue 2): Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Mat'
            do1ChnHist(chns1[i], dst_mask, dst_hist, dst_cdf);  // ERROR(Issue 2)

            byte last = 0;

            Mat lut = new Mat(1, 256, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < src_cdf.Cols; j++)
            {
                double F1j = src_cdf(j);                    // ERROR (Issue 1)

                for (byte k = last; k < dst_cdf.Cols; k++)
                {
                    double F2k = dst_cdf(k);                // ERROR (Issue 1)

                    if (Math.Abs(F2k - F1j) < histmatch_epsilon || F2k > F1j)
                    {
                        lut(j) = k;                         // ERROR (Issue 1)
                        last = k;                   
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            CvInvoke.LUT(chns[i], lut, chns[i]);            //ERROR(Issue 2)
        }

        Mat res = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.Merge(chns, res);

        res.CopyTo(src);
    }

    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mat src = CvInvoke.Imread("e:/test/iO6S1m.png");
        Mat dst = CvInvoke.Imread("e:/test/kfku3m.png");
        Mat mask = new Mat(src.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 255);

        histMatchRGB(dst, mask, src, mask);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Direct translations between languages, programming or spoken/written, will almost never turn out well. Generally, for programming languages anyway, it's almost always better to reimplement the algorithm in the target language, rather than doing any translations at all. That will  usually make the resulting code better, more easy to read and understand and maintain (which is an important part), but also allows you to use the "standard library" and language features of the target language that might not have been available in the source language.

Comment: I've found that it is usually more effective to create a clr/cli wrapper around existing C++ code then to port from C++ to C#. That way you can build a dll from C++ and use it in C#.  10 minutes might be pushing it but this might be a nice introduction . https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes. Note : I totally agree with @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1):

> mask(p)

The compiler interprets this as a method call, but the `mask` is an object, so this does not work. I would assume you want to extract the element at that position. Since the `Mat` class does not seem to contain an indexer you might have to use [`GetData`](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/f415d03e-4bf7-ffe6-9456-4980b436ae87.htm) or [`GetDataPointer`](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/d81986ca-8d79-d258-4691-77ad9d43cc3b.htm) to either convert the matrix to a array, or use a unsafe pointer for access.

> chns[i]

I would assume the intent is to extract a single channel. For this there seem to be the [`split`](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/ff3a9cd6-b726-b9d9-3be9-128a1cba7dbb.htm) method

Overall, you need to have some idea of what the code is doing, and read the [documentation](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm) to find equivalent ways to do things.